# MultipartReader awful performance or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

For some reason upload + save (or re-upload to FTP) via MultipartReader seems to be very slow. No matter what I try (save to local file via `new FileStream` or upload to FTP via `FtpWebRequest`), it's painfully slow. We're talking 1-4 MB/s.

I have tried adjusting [the default buffer size of 4KB](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities/MultipartReader.cs#L19) to anything between 1KB and 32KB. The higher the buffer is, the worse the performance is.

```
public async Task Upload()
{
    var request = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;

    var boundary = request.GetMultipartBoundary();
    var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, request.Body);

    MultipartSection section;

    while ((section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync()) != null)
    {
        var fileSection = section.AsFileSection();

        if (fileSection != null)
        {
            var fileName = fileSection.FileName;

            var stream = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\100MB.bin", FileMode.Create);

            await section.Body.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

I am directly saving the file via the `HttpContext.Request.Body` stream, so the files aren't cached, buffered, or anything like that. I do not want to keep the files in memory or on disk, as the end goal is to upload them via FTP and not save to disk as I've shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I found an answer. According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copytoasync?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1) the default buffer size for CopyTo is 81920, which is 80KB. I noticed a few people wrote that you should try tweaking this, so I set it to 8192 instead, which now results in it being basically instant. Upload to FTP takes 10 seconds for a 1GB file, which is pretty close to gigabit speeds. Very happy with that result.